# Reference for passive scalar

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, turbulence, stochastic-processes

I would like to learn about turbulence of a scalar advected by a random velocity field. I know that this problem can be solved analytically and that the statistics of the scalar field are intermittent.

I have read [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v405/n6787/abs/405639a0.html) which is a nice introduction but not detailed enough and am reading [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0105199v1) which I am finding very hard.

The passive scalar is an old problem. Do you know of any textbook where it's solution is explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first complete study was performed by Obukhov in 1949 with his famous paper *The structure of the temperature field in a turbulent flow*. You can find it here [[link]](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=AD0683016&hl=fr&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0bi9DaWpALG6urt4mrFHQUqsq0Cw&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ei=C7hQVZnzFuS6ygOQmIDYAQ&ved=0CCAQgAMoADAA) (This is a PDF file, you can check by searching the report title on Google). It is a nice thing to know.

A complete review was written by Warhaft in the Annual Review of Fluid Mechanics in 2000 [[link]](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.fluid.32.1.203). The paper title is *Passive Scalar in Turbulent Flows*. It is a really complete review, and the best starting point I think. You can then follow some references he provides.

If you want a textbook, I think that Tennekes & Lumley wrote something about passive scalar in the classic *A First Course in Turbulence*.

And finally, you can find papers dealing with different aspects of passive scalar by looking at some common journals, [Journal of Fluid Mechanics](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/quickSearch;jsessionid=54225DF6F5109B1F61E54297BCBD8204.journals?jid=FLM&search=passive%20scalar&), [Physics of Fluids](http://scitation.aip.org/search;jsessionid=eb2edrhnh5khn.x-aip-live-06?value1=passive%20scalar&option1=all&option912=resultCategory&value912=ResearchPublicationContent&operator8=AND&option8=pub_serialIdent&value8=aip%2Fjournal%2Fpof2&qs=true), [Journal of Turbulence](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/doSearch?quickLinkJournal=&journalText=&AllField=passive%20scalar&publication=40001526) or [Journal of Fluids Engineering](http://fluidsengineering.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/solr/searchresults.aspx?q=passive%20scalar&f_ContentType=Journals&f_JournalDisplayName=Journal%20of%20Fluids%20Engineering&ResourceTypeID=2&SearchSourceType=3).